# Convert an angle

Tags: homework-and-exercises, units

Can someone show me a formula in order to convert an angle from [V] to degree or rad? (i use aPotentiometer measuring steering angle)

Edit: Well let me exlpain it. I photo of my experiment is shown below. I apply a force to my material and measure the torsion angle with a potentiometer. For example for P=1,18 bar , θ=1,67 V. I want to convert V into degrees or rad. My only clue is that at the full extent of the piston the angle indication in V is 5,33 V –

[image]

Comment: I can understand why to close this question.Instead of vote against me let me know where i am wrong

Comment: In SI units, $V$ denotes Volts, which is a measure of potential, and cannot be converted to a unit of measure for an angle, e.g. degrees. Can you elaborate on what measurement you've made?

Comment: Please give more details about the experiment. What do you mean by "steering angle"? As written I don't consider this question answerable.

Comment: Well let me exlpain it. This is my experiment http://prntscr.com/3qxzmb . I apply a force to my material and measure the torsion angle with a potentiometer. For example for P=1,18 bar , θ=1,67 V. I want to convert V into degrees or rad. My only clue is that at the full extent of the piston the  angle indication in V is  5,33 V

Comment: Information like the previous comment *must* be included for the question to be sensible; how did you expected people to know how you had set things up if you didn't tell them? Further, that data should be edited into the questions rather than left in a comment.

Comment: I'll be checking regularly to see if the questions has been updated and re-open it, or you can flag for moderator attention after you have fixed it.

Answer (score 1):

OK, so, you need to know another piece of information, which is the total angle of motion possible from the potentiometer.  Typically, for a non-multiturn pot, it might be something like 270°.

Then the ratio of the measured voltage to the total voltage possible is the fraction of the 270° total travel.  So if you measured 75% of the maximum voltage, then the pot is at 75% of 270°, or 202.5°

TTFN